# Java - NoClassDefFoundError, Android lib project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I create library project in eclipse - LibProject1.
Than I create library project - LibProject2 that use LibProject1.
Than I create Android App that use LibProject2.

If I add LibProject2 to Android App like: `Right click on project -> properties -> Android -> Add -> add LibProject2`.  App runs without errors.

I want to create jar file for LibProject2 that contains LibProject1 and add jar to Android App.

I do: 
`LibProject2 -> Right click on project -> Export -> Java -> JAR file -> finish`.

When i run app i get `NoClassDefFoundError`, no found LibProject1 class.
In JD-GUI i see that LibProject2 contains LibProject1.
Where is a problem? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
right click on project >
   then to project properties > 
      java build path >
        last tab order and export
```

there you see those jar unchecked. first check it then [clean and rebuild]... 
It will work. cheers :)